Definition of Riemann integral using $\displaystyle\lim_{N\to +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i)(x_{i+1} - x_i)$
In this classical mechanics video, professor defines the integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$ as the limit as $N$ tends to infinity of the sum of the rectangles over a partition $\{x_1=a, x_2,..., x_{N-1}, x_N =b\}$ where the width of one rectangle is $x_{i+1} - x_i$ and the length is $f(x_i)$.
With this presentation, isn't there a risk to have cases where $\{ x_1=a, x_2 =a , x_3 =a , ... , x_{N-1} = a, x_N = b\}$ so that $N$ indeed increases to infinity but the partitions stay $\{a,b \}$ ?
Perhaps that's why this way of presenting the integral is less preferred than the traditional one ("there exist a number $L$ such that for every $\epsilon$, there exists a partition $P'$, such that for every partition $P$ finer than $P'$ and for any $t_i$ in $[x_i, x_{i+1}]$, the Riemann sum over $P$ taking all $t_i$'s ($i$ from $1$ to $N$) is within $(L-\epsilon, L+\epsilon$)") ?
Thanks in advance.

There are a number of tiny inconsistencies:

first of all, when you define $N$ point, you only have $N-1$ intervals, and for $i=N$, $x_{i+1}$ is not defined: the sum should only be $\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{N-1} f(x_i)(x_{i+1} - x_i)$
what makes the sum converge is not directly the number of points but the maximum size of the individual intervals. If you only say that the number of points increases to infinity, you have not a sufficient condition
if you only use one single sum and not a majorant and a minorant one, you implicitely assume that the function is continuous: that condition should be explicit.

So a possible expression of the property could be: if $f$ is a function defined and continuous on an interval $\left[a;b\right]$, the Riemann integral of $f$ on $\left[a;b\right]$ is:
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i)(x_{i+1} - x_i)$$
where for $i\in {\Bbb N}, 1\le i\le N+1, x_i=a+(i-1)\dfrac{b-a}N$

$3^{rd}$ point: Could you please provide me more information about the relation between continuity and the majorant and minorant sum, I've never heard of it and it interests me!
$2^{nd}$ point: I think we could say the number of points makes the sum converge if we add Koren Parkhov's condition

@niobium: imagine the function $f$ defined on $\left[0; 1\right]$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x\in {\Bbb Q}$ else $f(x)=1$. All the sums will be $0$, but the function is not Riemann integrable on $\left[0; 1\right]$. If you use sums of majorant and minorant on the individual intervals, the sums of minorant will be $0$ while the sum of majorant will be $1$, which is consistent with the fact that the function is not integrable.

For your second point, $x_0<x_1<...<x_N$ is not a sufficient condition. Imagine that for interval $\left[0; 1\right]$,  we use a regular partition of $0,0.1$ with $x_0...x_{N-1}$, and $x_N=1$. Do you expect that the sums will converge to the Riemann integral, for example for the function $x\mapsto x^2$ on $\left[0; 1\right]$?

The classical definition assumes $x_0<x_1<...<x_n$ . indeed, if we allow the partition you suggested, there is a problem and the limit might not exist.

Koren Parkhov's answer hit on one of your points, the case of "degenerate" rectangles. That is resolved by assuming that a partition takes the form
$$
x_0 = a < x_1 < x_2 < \cdots < x_{n-1} < x_n = b
$$
That said, there is also an additional oversight with this definition, in that you could have partitions which still meet this condition, but do not have $\|P\| \to 0$. Say, for $[0,1]$, a partition given by the first $n$ elements of the sequence
$$
x_k := \begin{cases}
0, & k=1 \\
1-\frac{1}{k}, & k>1
\end{cases}
$$
That results in a sequence of partitions where $\|P\| = \frac 1 2$.
I imagine, as is often done, the professor is making the assumption of an equally spaced partition; that is, the $x_i$ are $\frac{b-a}{n}$ apart, when you want $n$ rectangles, i.e.
$$
x_{i+1} = x_i + \frac{b-a}{n}
$$
This is usually the standard approach when introducing the integral in a Calculus I course. In that case, things work out fine since $\|P\| \to 0$ for those partitions as $n \to \infty$.

The mesh of your example does converge to $0$ (I think the mesh formula is $\frac{1}{n(n-1)}$)

No, the mesh is defined as the maximum distance between consecutive points.
